# how to find a controller in appdelegate

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanna initialize dataModel for a controller called CategoryPickerViewController in appdelegate.
but I can't get my target controller correctly.
The console keeps telling me

> uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

I know something is wrong with the [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4usdA.png) index stuff, but I don't know how to fix it.

I can locate the first controller by using"viewControllers.first" or "[0]"

```
let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    
    if let tabViewController = tabController.viewControllers {
        
        let navController = tabViewController[0] as! 
UINavigationController
        
        let controller = navController.viewControllers[2] as! 
CategoryPickerViewController

        controller.dataModel = dataModel
```

Initialize dataModel for a controller called CategoryPickerViewController in appdelegate[storyboard here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqJvA.png)

this picture in the link above is my storyboard.
according to you nice guys who are helping me.i think the promblem is caused by not making the controller as a child controller,so i just can't catch my controller by using for loop.and the parent controller is a knowledge i have never learned before.maybe i need to learn that now.

[my controllers view in x-mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4usdA.png)
this picture is much clearer

according to @MShah , i printed the controllers of the navcontroller[0],and the result is  "MyLocations.CurrentLocationViewController: 0x7fd13506fc00"
so the CatelogePickerVC is actually not belong to the navcontroller,right?

Comment: i got three tabs,the target controller is a tableviewcontroller which is in the first tab,im sure that's my target..

Comment: I think the navigation controller has no child ViewControllers. Can you give me more clues?

Comment: You hare accessing 2nd Index of  Navigation Controller's viewController. not Tabbar's view controller. Make sure your nav controller has 3 or more view controller

Comment: i just added a picture of my controller maps by x-mind,maybe it can help you understand my meaning,and thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: print list of view controllers within that navigation stack by adding following line `print(navController.viewControllers)` and add that print as part of your question to better understand your navigation stack.

Comment: i did it @MShah

Comment: yes, it's not part of that navigation stack.

Comment: can you add 2 more prints to code mentioned by @dreamBegin `if let navController = vController as? UINavigationController {
                    print("Navigation Stack consists of \(navController.viewControllers)")
                    for subVc in navController.viewControllers {
                        print("VC desc\(subVc.description)")
                    }
                }`

Comment: it just make me believe that controller is not one of the navController[0],the results are three viewcontrollers that just next to the three navcontrollers.now i just want to know how to make CategoryPickerViewController available for me....T.T

Comment: embed each tab within uinavigationcontroller and then it should work. added screenshot on how to embed if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever use force typecasting. The error you are getting is you are accessing an out of bound (more/less then value present in array) index in an array. Maybe this example help you :-

```
if let tabController = self.window.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    for vController in tabController.viewControllers {
        if vController is UINavigationController {
            //Do anything with navigation controller
            print("Navigation controller")
        }else if vController is CategoryPickerViewController {
            //Do anything with CategoryPickerViewController controller
            print("CategoryPickerViewController controller")
        }
    }
}
```

Edits according to screenshot

```
if let tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,let controllers = tabController.viewControllers {
    for vController in controllers {
        if let navController = vController as? UINavigationController {
            for subVc in navController.viewControllers {
                if subVc is CategoryPickerViewController{
                    // Do the required stuff with CategoryPickerViewController
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for loop is very helpful but i cant grab my controller.it seems not belong to the navcontroller[0] at all！im so confused.maybe you can help me by the picture i just uploaded in the question

Comment: thank you ! but it seems still not right to me...-.-i think it's something wrong with the controller itself

Comment: this code works 100% maybe you should check your flow and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Select each tab View controller and click on Editor ->Embed->Navigation Controller]

Try this way with for loop, so no need to specify index. If navigation controller stack consists of view controllers of type category picker controller then it will be able to safely cast the same :-

```
let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

            if let tabViewController = tabController.viewControllers {

                let navController = tabViewController[0] as!
                UINavigationController

                //let controller = navController.viewControllers[2] as!
               // SecondVC
                for vc in navController.viewControllers {
                    if let controller = vc as? CategoryPickerViewController {
                        controller.dataModel = dataModel
                    }
                }
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot but i still can't get my controller.maybe it's not in(or belong to?) that navcontroller at all.emmm,i just added a picture in my question.